# Grails "Null Pointer Exception" when trying to update items in list

Tags: angularjs, grails

I can add items to my grails app without a problem, and when I display them it looks like this:

```
[{"class":"server.Item","id":1,"assignedTo":"a","comments":null,
"completed":false,"creator":"a","name":"l","priority":"2","type":"Work"}]
```

Just a list of JSON objects, it works perfectly, it persists in my client etc.

However, when I try to update, I get a null pointer exception:

```
2015-05-26 11:56:33,504 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - 
NullPointerException occurred when processing request: 
[OPTIONS]     /server/todoList/updateList
Cannot set property 'name' on null object. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot set property 'name' on null object
```

My update controller looks like this:

```
def updateList() {
    def newItem = Item.findById(request.JSON.id)
    newItem.name = request.JSON.name
    newItem.type = request.JSON.type
    newItem.priority = request.JSON.priority
    newItem.completed = request.JSON.completed
    newItem.comments = request.JSON.comments
    newItem.creator = request.JSON.creator
    newItem.assignedTo = request.JSON.assignedTo
    newItem.save(flush: true)
    render newItem as JSON
}
```

It is called here in my angular controller:

```
$scope.updateList = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
       // serverList.save({command: 'updateList'}, item);
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/server/todoList/updateList', item)
            .success(function(response) {})
            .error(function(response) {alert("Failed to update");});
    });
};
```

Here are the properties of my item:

```
 name: $scope.thing,
 type: $scope.worktypeSelection,
 priority: $scope.prioritySelection,
 completed: false,
 comments: '',
 creator: $scope.username,
 assignedTo: $scope.assign.name
```

Comment: When called from angular, does `item` have `id` in it?

Comment: No, here is where item is declared:
http://pastebin.com/zmTwKd1f

Comment: pastebin may not be accessible. Add contents to question.

Comment: Are you sure that the item (which you load by ID) is really in the database hence not null? I suspect it's the assignment `newItem.name = request.JSON.name` that causes the code to fail.

Comment: If I list Item with Item.list(), all of the appropriate items are there.